# finding preceding and succeeding value of a number - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any pythonic way to find preceding and succeeding value of a number? All I want to delete the number if preceding and succeeding numbers are also same.

Comment: Please show an example of your input and expected output, as well as your attempt. I have no idea what your problem is at the moment. More pythonic than what?

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove duplicate values in an ordered dataframe. As per @dspencer, you should include some sample data for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#suppose we have a list of values
list = [1,2,2,2,3,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,9,9]
print('Full list')
print(list)

#writing indexes values which are equal to their preceeding and succeeding neighbours to another list:
indexes = []
x=1
y=0
z=2
for i in list[1:-1]:
  if list[x] == list[y] == list[z]:
    indexes.append(x)    
  x=x+1
  y=y+1
  z=z+1

#removing them from list
for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
    del list[index]

#printing result
print('List without values which are equal to their preceeding and succeeding neighbours:')
print(list)
```